# packer: Build type vmware-iso using ova as source

Tags: vmware, packer, ova

In `packer`, when using `"type": "virtualbox-ovf"` it is possible to define a base `ova` using:

```
"source_path": "file://{{user `pwd`}}/server-base.ova",
```

This option [does not seem to be available](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/vmware-iso.html) when building with `"type": "vmware-iso"`

Is there an alternative way for building with VMWare provider, starting from a base `.ova`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`vmware-vmx`](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/vmware-vmx.html). If you have an OVA, use [`ovftool`](https://pubs.vmware.com/application-manager-on-premise-15/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.connector.doc_prem_15%2FGUID-3EC77DB6-9E81-4F42-9D57-8DC5F0037141.html) to convert it before running Packer.